# Issue about the newest Contacts ios Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, cncontact

I'm working on my app and at a certain point the user can convince their friends to download it. However, the `ABAddressBook` framework ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007099)) has been deprecated with iOS 9, so I had to teach myself the newest `Contacts` framework [(link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328).

However, I'm still facing issues. I have read the documentation up to this point:

```
NSArray *keysToFetch = @[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];

    NSString *containerId = [self.CN_contacts defaultContainerIdentifier];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];

    self.allContacts = [self.CN_contacts unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keysToFetch error:nil];
```

But I know that the block of code is missing the functionality of asking the user to grant access to their contacts.

Does anyone knows a way to ask user with `CNAuthorizationStatus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like this

```
switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts)
        {
            case CNAuthorizationStatus.Denied,CNAuthorizationStatus.Restricted :
             //Handle denied and restricted case
             break
            case CNAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined :
             //Request Access
            contactsStore?.requestAccessForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts, completionHandler: { (granted, error) -> Void in
                //At this point an alert is provided to the user to provide access to contacts. 
                //This will get invoked if a user responds to the alert
                if  (!granted ){
                    //User has allowed the access in the alertview provided
                }
                else{
                    //User has decline the access in the alertview provided
                }
            })
             break
            case  CNAuthorizationStatus.Authorized :
             //Do your stuff

             NSArray *keysToFetch = @[CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
             NSString *containerId = [self.CN_contacts defaultContainerIdentifier];
             NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
             self.allContacts = [self.CN_contacts unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keysToFetch error:nil];

             break
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the great answer man, but precisely in my question: how to request/ask that authorization ? what's the way to do ? That's the same approach like User's location ?